# Handlebars loop to assign value to attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have values of array which the length is dynamic. But I have image holder of 4. Means If the length of the array is 2, I will have 2 filled holder and left 2 empty holder. The unfilled holder will be simply `div`

I've tried with below code but that doesn't suite my needs, because it will produce the `div` according to the length of the arrays.

```
{{#each product.image}}
<div style="background-image:url(http://example.com/{{this}})"></div>
{{/each}}
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want max number of 4 divs, filled up with data that is there and left empty if no data than you can use a custom helper function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('times', function (index, options) {
        var result = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       if(options.data.root.product.image[i]){
          result += '<div style="background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org'+options.data.root.product.image[i]+')"></div>';
       } else {
          result += '<div>empty div</div>';
       }       
   }
   return result;
});
```

and then in your html:

```
{{#times this}}
{{/times}}
```

Check fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ga0oh2to/)

Comment: you missed understood. I want to have a loop that has a max length of 4, and fill in whatever array to the 4.